# Unable to Deploy Telescope

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, telescope

I'm really new at this, but I've been fiddling around trying to deploy Telescope to my Digital Ocean account through Meteor. Please help. I've hit a wall.

I've gotten far enough where I've done mup setup successfully.

However, when I do mup deploy, I get a FAILED.

I am curious if my set up of folders and files are correct.

I am in root/projectname when I type "mup setup". mup.json and setting.json are in that folder. Then I have a folder under "appname" with my app, which only has the .meteor files.

mup.json edited to location of "app": "appname",

Here is the error below,

```
****gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/deploythisbook/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    gyp info ok 
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `mup logs -f` in another terminal window while you're deploying. This might give you some indications on the actual problem. A common issue is having the wrong Node version configured in your `mup.json`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. I would've been struggling with that for even more hours. I couldn't find this issue mentioned anywhere in the instructions.

The Node version needed to be updated to the latest version which was stated from mup logs -f.

Comment: It's actually mentioned in the "Troubleshooting" section of the Meteor Up docs: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/#troubleshooting (I wrote it ;)